# How to click on button with selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

my HTML-Code is following:

```
<button aria-label="Nur zuhören" aria-disabled="false" class=
"jumbo--Z12Rgj4 buttonWrapper--x8uow audioBtn--1H6rCK">
```

and I want to click on the button with following Python-Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "jumbo--Z12Rgj4 buttonWrapper--x8uow audioBtn--1H6rCK"))).click
```

but it's not working

Comment: `but it's not working`. Any more details? Nothing happens? Exception is thrown? Your pc explodes?

Comment: it can't find the button "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a element with multiple class name, you can use XPATH.

I simplify you html as `<button class="aaa bbb ccc">`

Then you can use `(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'aaa') and contains(@class, 'bbb') and contains(@class, 'ccc')]")` to find this button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture the element in webelement and then try to execute the expected condition command. It should work

click_ele=driver.find_element_by_class_name(jumbo--Z12Rgj4 buttonWrapper--x8uow audioBtn--1H6rCK)

wait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(click_ele.click)))

***wait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "jumbo--Z12Rgj4 buttonWrapper--x8uow audioBtn--1H6rCK"))).click***

.click might not be coming as an option in the dropdown, as it take 2 positional arguments

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can't find `multiple class names` by `class name` instead use `css selector.`

Try below **css** selector.

```
wait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".jumbo--Z12Rgj4.buttonWrapper--x8uow.audioBtn--1H6rCK"))).click()
```

OR

```
wait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Nur zuhören']"))).click()
```

Hope this helps.